# Creating an Array JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a variable from a title attribute tile="Red, Blue". Is there a simple way to make this an array. So the array has 2 values "Red" & "Blue"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean splitting string?

```
var title = "Red, Blue";
var titleArray = title.split(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array as :

```
var title = "Red, Blue";
var array = tile.split(',');
```

OR ,

```
var array1 = document.getElementById('yourElementID')
                      .getAttribute('tile').split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
var myArray = new Array("Red","Blue");
```